# SystemError with spidev after upgrade

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, spidev

**I'm getting the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/hydro1/hydroponic_newloop.py", line 6, in 
import spidev
SystemError: Type does not define the tp_name field.
Here is the relevant code:**

```
#import os
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
import time
import datetime
import spidev
from twilio.rest import Client
#from time import sleep
import csv
# Define I/O pins on PI
shutdown_trigger = 2
water_full_pin = 4
water_empty_pin = 5
water_on_pin = 6
irregation_on_pin = 13
fertilizer_empty_pin = 17
fertilizer_on_pin = 27
bubbler_on_pin = 22
water_heater_on_pin = 26
# Set up I/O pins on PI
GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setup(shutdown_trigger, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(water_full_pin, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(water_empty_pin, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(water_on_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(irregation_on_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(fertilizer_empty_pin, GPIO.IN)
GPIO.setup(fertilizer_on_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(bubbler_on_pin, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(water_heater_on_pin, GPIO.OUT)
# Initialize Output Pins to OFF on PI
GPIO.output(water_on_pin, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(shutdown_trigger, GPIO.HIGH)
GPIO.output(fertilizer_on_pin, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(bubbler_on_pin, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(irregation_on_pin, GPIO.LOW)
GPIO.output(water_heater_on_pin, GPIO.LOW)

# Open SPI bus for MCP3008 adc
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)
spi.max_speed_hz=1000000
# Define sensor channels on MCP3008 adc
air_temp_channel = 0
water_temp_channel  = 1
battery_level_channel = 2
soil_moisture_channel = 3
grove_tds_channel = 4
# Function to read SPI data from MCP3008 chip
# Channel must be an integer 0-7
def ReadChannel(channel):
    adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
    data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
    return data
```

**it worked previously but failed after upgrades. running Python 3.9.2. Any ideas?**

Comment: What *OS* are you on (looks like a *Nix*)? What *SPIDev* (*Python* module) version do you have? How did you install it?

Comment: Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye), spidev  2.0. I don't remember how I installed it.

Comment: Home-page: http://github.com/doceme/py-spidev

Comment: I already visited those pagers. The module is written in *C* and requires build. that's why I asked, as it's important. Also the repository is idle for almost 2 years.

Comment: thanks ChristiFati. I reinstalled the module with a more recent version and it works great.